# Output: Calendar Month (without native calendar generating functions)

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, date

Upon receiving month and year in YYYYMM format, generate output of the corresponding **calendar month** for that year.

For example the input `201312` should generate the following output:

```
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31
```

Only trick is, NO native calendar generating functions... so Linux clones, no "cal" function... Muahahahahah!

PS: The calendar must start out with Monday as the left-most day, this is to ensure that the output is like the "cal" function, but does not output like "cal", which has Sunday as its left-most day...

Smallest code size wins.

Comment: You want it to look like a calendar, might want to change your text to say that more clearly. Also, what are the winning conditions?

Comment: @Quincunx, you're like my conscience, only digital...

Comment: Except I'm not digital...

Comment: Close enough, buddy... You're just pixels on a screen here ;)

Comment: So... Winning conditions?

Comment: "Smallest size wins." size of what? If it is code size, then please change the tag to code-golf

Comment: I presume you want the Gregorian calendar, but for what range of years?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Python 2.7 - 152

Unfortunately it fails for [September 1752](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_%28New_Style%29_Act_1750). Granted, it imports all of the calender functions, but only *uses* 1, and that just returns the start day of the week and the number of days.

```
from calendar import*
w,l=monthrange(*divmod(input(),100))
print" Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su\n"+"   "*w+''.join(["%3d"%s+"\n"*((s+w)%7<1)for s in range(1,l+1)])
```

Relatively standard code, but this is my favourite bit:

```
"\n"*((s+w)%7<1)
```

It prints the new line using string multiplication, if the number of the current day and start day of the week is Sunday (e.g. 7) as the boolean is cast to an integer.

This saves a character on the more intuitive `x%7==0` by using `x%7<1` instead.

Test output:

```
> 198210
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Comment: let me guess: you have just translated my approach to another language and it came up shorter. I'm okay with that, but disclosure would be nice.

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh no. Not at all. I couldn't even understand yours. To be honest, given the verbose imports I needed, I was shocked it was going to come close to beating yours. Just out of curiousity what is `52.times` doing? Its not multiplication?

Comment: It's a looping construct. `n.times{...}` is identical to `(0...n).each{...}` or `0.upto(n-1){...}`. Multiplication would be `52 * ...`

Comment: @JanDvorak
I played with Python a few years ago in a job I was working in... I found the indent syntax a little bit of a pain... So used to curly brackets I guess... 

LOVE the "\n"*((s+w)%7<1) trick... I've never checked to see if this would work in JavaScript... ;)

Comment: The Wiki reference you mentioned was interesting... "It reformed the calendar of England and British Dominions so that a new year began on 1 January rather than 25 March (Lady Day) and would run according to the Gregorian calendar, as used in most of western Europe."

I'm surprised the English were a little behind then...?

Comment: But the output is wrong? October 1982 still had 31 days.

Comment: @user113215 Good catch, that was output from an earlier version that wasn't working. The code in the answer does give the correct calendar (except for September 1752).

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby, <del>170</del> 168 characters

```
g=gets.to_i
require'date'
d=Date.new g/100,g%100
puts'Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su'
l=['']*(d.jd%7)+[*1..(d>>1).jd-d.jd]
56.times{|i|$><<"#{l[i].to_s.rjust 2} #{?\n if i%7>5}"}
```

Bugfix: didn't require the neccessary library (+16)
used julian date modulo 7 instead of current week day directly (-3)
used /100 and %100 to parse date instead of regex (-13). Taken from LegoStormtroopr's answer.
removed the parentheses around the argument to `rjust` and `Date.new`(-2)

Comment: Cool. Not tested exhaustively, but seems that you can change `"#{l[i].to_s.rjust 2} #{?\n if i%7>5}"` with `"%2s %s"%[l[i],i%7>5?$/:""]`.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica 203

```
g@d_:=Module[{w={"Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa","Su"},c},
c@n_:=" "~ Table ~{n};
Grid@Partition[Join[w,c[Position[w,StringTake[ToString@DayName@d,2]][[1,1]]-1],
Range@DayCount[d,d~DatePlus~{1,"Month"}],c@6],7]]
```

**Testing**

```
g[{2013, 12}]
g[{2014, 1}]
g[{2014, 2}]
```

[image: calendars]

Comment: Great use of Mathematica!

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 87 bytes

```
k§2vẎṄ,4ȯI:£3<?4ẎIεD4/⌊‟₁/⌊N‟:400/⌊»∧+ż↵`»8τv‹¥Ẏt2Ṡ7%7ε¤w$ẋf»∇ė{»4τ¥Ẏt28+ɾJ7ẇƛƛS2↳;Ṅ;⁋,
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=k%C2%A72v%E1%BA%8E%E1%B9%84%2C4%C8%AFI%3A%C2%A33%3C%3F4%E1%BA%8EI%CE%B5D4%2F%E2%8C%8A%E2%80%9F%E2%82%81%2F%E2%8C%8AN%E2%80%9F%3A400%2F%E2%8C%8A%C2%BB%E2%88%A7%2B%C5%BC%E2%86%B5%60%C2%BB8%CF%84v%E2%80%B9%C2%A5%E1%BA%8Et2%E1%B9%A07%257%CE%B5%C2%A4w%24%E1%BA%8Bf%C2%BB%E2%88%87%C4%97%7B%C2%BB4%CF%84%C2%A5%E1%BA%8Et28%2B%C9%BEJ7%E1%BA%87%C6%9B%C6%9BS2%E2%86%B3%3B%E1%B9%84%3B%E2%81%8B%2C&inputs=%27201312%27&header=&footer=)

-7 thanks to lyxal.

```
=== Part 1: Header ===
k§      # Monday to Sunday
  2vẎ   # Get first two letters of each
     Ṅ, # Join by spaces
=== Part 2: What day does it start? ===
4ȯI                                          # Last two (month) as integer
   :£                                        # Store a copy to register
     3<?4ẎIε                                 # Decrement the year if the month is Jan or Feb 
            D                                # Calculate:
             4/⌊‟                            # floor(y/4)
                 ₁/⌊N‟                       # -floor(y/100)
                      :                      # y
                       400/⌊                 # And floor(y/400)
                            »...»8τv‹        # Compressed list of the days (mod 7) at the start of each month
                                     ¥Ẏt     # Get the correct item
                                        2    # Add 2 (1 because first day of month, 1 because it ends on Sunday)
                                         Ṡ7% # Take the sum of the whole thing, mod 7.
=== Part 3: Get the whole month ===
7ε                     # Difference from 7
  ¤w$ẋf                # Copies of the empty string
       »...»4τ         # Compressed list of days in each month, -28
              ¥Ẏt      # Get the correct item
                 28+   # Add 28
                    ɾ  # Make a range out of that
                     J # Add on the empty strings
=== Part 4: Format nicely ===
7ẇ           # Divide into chunks of 7
  ƛ      ;   # Foreach...
   ƛ   ;     # For each item...
    S        # Stringify
     2↳      # Align
        Ṅ    # Join by spaces
          ⁋, # Output joined by newlines
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=k%C2%A72wvi%E1%B9%84%2C4%C8%AFI%3A%C2%A33%3C%3F4%E1%BA%8EI%CE%B5D4%2F%E2%8C%8A%E2%80%9F%E2%82%81%2F%E2%8C%8AN%E2%80%9F%3A400%2F%E2%8C%8A%C2%BB%E2%88%A7%2B%C5%BC%E2%86%B5%60%C2%BB8%CF%84v%E2%80%B9%C2%A5%E1%BA%8Et2%E1%B9%A07%257%CE%B5%C2%A4w%24%E1%BA%8Bf%C2%BB%E2%88%87%C4%97%7B%C2%BB4%CF%84%C2%A5%E1%BA%8Et28%2B%C9%BEJ7%E1%BA%87%C6%9B%C6%9BS2%E2%86%B3%3B%E1%B9%84%3B%E2%81%8B%2C&inputs='201312'&header=&footer=) for 88 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC, 204 bytes

```
INPUT Y$Y$[3]=Y$[3]+"/
DTREAD Y$+"/01"OUT Y,M,,W
W=W-1+!W*7?"Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
FOR I=1TO 30+(1AND M-(M>7))-(M==2)*2+(Y MOD 4<1&&(Y MOD 100||Y MOD 400<1))LOCATE W*3,?STR$(I,2);
W=W+1
IF W>6 THEN W=0?
NEXT
```

Wow, that leap year detector is VERY long...

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>153</s> 147 bytes

```
Mo Di We Th Fr Sa Su
<?=str_pad("",3*$w=date(w,$t=strtotime(chunk_split($argv[1],4,"-")."7")));while($d++<date(t,$t))printf("%2d "."
"[++$w%7],$d);
```

**breakdown**

```
echo"Mo Di We Th Fr Sa Su\n";   // header
echo str_pad("",3*                      // 4. print leading spaces
    $w=date(w,                          // 3. get weekday
    $t=strtotime(                       // 2. convert to unix timestamp
        chunk_split($argv[1],4,"-")."7" // 1. import, split to year-month-, append day 7
)));
while($d++<date(t,$t))                  // 5. loop $d through days of month:
    printf("%2d "."\n"[++$w%7],$d);         // print date, plus a linebreak for sundays
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (239)

```
h=prompt();y=h.slice(i=0,4);m=h[4]+h[5]-1;d=new Date(y,m);a='MoTuWeThFrSaSu'.match(/../g);for(p=0;p<(d.getDay()||7)-1;p++)a.push('  ');while(d.setDate(++i)&&d.getMonth()==m)a.push(9<i?i:' '+i);while(c=a.splice(0,7).join(' '))console.log(c)
```

Output:

```
(for 198210)                (for 201312)

Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su        Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3                           1
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10         2  3  4  5  6  7  8
11 12 13 14 15 16 17         9 10 11 12 13 14 15
18 19 20 21 22 23 24        16 17 18 19 20 21 22
25 26 27 28 29 30 31        23 24 25 26 27 28 29
                            30 31
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 242 bytes

Not the most elegant solution, I suspect.

Input in the form of an integer with the four high digits forming the year, and the low two digits the month.

```c
X=100,W;f(d){int m=d%X,y=d/X,i=0,M=" >8><><>><><>"[m]/2+(m==2&(!(y%4)&&(y%X|!(y%400))));for(m+=m<3?y--,10:-2,W=(((1+(26*m-2)/10-2*y/X+5*(y%X)/4+y/X/4)%7)+6)%7,printf("Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su\n%*s",3*W,"");i<M;)printf("%2d%c",++i,W++%7^6?32:10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU9BboMwEDw3r3AtGa2xLWxDCYpxcuuNUyKB1LRSBKXlAIlIOKA0b6cuSm/trjSr0eyMdkvxUZbTVFglJc9NDRW9Nt0FtbYiBR9tFRS8sZJnFqN1sk5dz4Bf2tdAM2it1R48wkgi6nluFF8zkZK6MvWxh5bZNg03oxBcyZXQPLcAoBjo2G@FpoGSQvtjULAn/yeABhFzLIgoWVIWO@Sn3t1UA86OaDeg/B3tPtFzj7YHtB32HfHPmId@zjGmpkkzQ3/3ia5IiTljDc8ZI8u3eBPqlZLU3Kb5y0PTAV1cFw81aKlCpalBp@FyBrzvhBAu7y4lMvlHkpH8w3VD0zc)

Comment: Suggest `(13*m+4)/5+y%X*5/4-7*y/X/4` instead of `1+(26*m-2)/10-2*y/X+5*(y%X)/4+y/X/4`

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 183 chars

```
L←{(0=400∣⍵)∨(0≠25∣⍵)∧0=4∣⍵}⋄C←{Y←(30+2741⊤⍨12/2)+(¯2+L⍵[2])×2=⍳12⋄d←7∣+/Y[⍳⍵[1]-1],{1+L⍵}1900..⍵[2]-1⋄7 7⍴(,/7 2⍴'MoTuWeThFrSaSu'),(d⍴⊂''),{2 0⍕⍵}¨(⍳Y[⍵[1]]),12⍴⊂''}∘{(100∣⍵),⌊⍵÷100}
```

Input ok only from 1900. Test & how to use it:

```
    C 201312         
 Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su 
                    1 
  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
 30 31                
    C 202312        
 Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su 
              1  2  3 
  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```