# Last Week Day Of The Month

Tags: code-golf, string, date

## Introduction

This challenge was inspired by a seemingly simple task requested at work that couldn't easily be done in Microsoft Teams. At least not from what we could find!

### Task

Your task, if you choose to accept it, is to output the last week day of **any month** in **any year**.

### Input

You can input the desired month/year in whatever format you like, but it must take in an input. Having these hard-coded into the calculations **doesn't count!**

Input examples include but are not limited to:

- `08/2023`
- `October 1678`
- `1/2067`

### Output

Your output must be the last week day of the month in the below format:

***Tuesday 31st***

### Test cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `10/2023` | `Tuesday 31st` |
| `February 2017` | `Tuesday 28th` |
| `09/1674` | `Friday 28th` |
| `1/2043` | `Friday 30th` |

### Assumptions / Stipulations

- You can assume the inputs are always in a workable format and not null
- Calendar is the [Gregorian Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#:%7E:text=The%20Gregorian%20calendar%20is%20the,replacement%20for%2C%20the%20Julian%20calendar.)
- Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday are all week days. Saturday and Sunday are NOT valid week days for this task
- You can ignore public holidays

PS. I got the test cases from [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2043)

### Current Winner (28th November 2023)

> PHP - [Kaddath](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90841/kaddath) - 55 Bytes
> https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266340/91342

Comment: First question here on Code-Golf, go easy if I forgot to add something obvious!

Comment: The output format might be overly restricted, as it requires hardcoding the day names if the language doesn't support it by default. Perhaps you can allow to output the day number, so Monday is 1, Tuesday is 2, and so on (and let the answer choose if it uses 0-indexing or 1-indexing)

Comment: `09/1674` should result in `Friday 28th`, see [here](https://www.generalblue.com/monthly-calendar/september-1674)

Comment: @Ajax1234 Looks like calendars continue to be the worst human invention... from the timeanddate.com website, the same month shows as Wednesday 30th, see here: https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/monthly.html?year=1674&month=9&country=9

Comment: @I.TDelinquent You've selected United Kingdom, which was still using the Julian Calendar at that time, not the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @CommandMaster Good shout! I may amend the rules depending on the answers but I do also like this restriction...

Comment: @Arnauld Holy! Good spot, I've updated the question with the correct value. THANK YOU to Ajax1234 with the orig correction!

Comment: Someone is going to do this in Excel and prove your opening line wrong :P

Comment: Having that fixed output format is a bit annoying... :-)

Comment: Does BC need to be supported?

Comment: @Bbrk24, It seems [you're right](/a/266279/39490).

Comment: If you don't want to take holidays into account, then why not just say "weekdays" instead of "working days"?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Good point! I'll update the question shortly :-)

Comment: Do leap years count?

Answer (score 7):

## Bash and GNU Date, <s>84</s> 83 bytes

Thanks to [gildux](/users/104387) for shaving 1 byte.

```sh
s=(1 2)
m=1$1+month
date -d$m-$((s[`date -d$m +%w`]+1))day +%A\ %eth|sed s/1th/1st/
```

Input format is the month name and year as a single word, e.g. `October2023` or `sep2026`.

An English locale (such as the standard `C` locale) is required for the day names to be in English.

You might need to unset `TZ` environment variable to get proleptic Gregorian dates.

---

#### How it works

1. **`m=1$1+month`**: Create a `date` input that is one month later than the start of the target month (ie. the first day of the following month).  GNU Date allows us to omit all the spaces, which is helpful.
2. **`date -d$m +%w`**: Obtain the day of week of the first day of the following month.
3. **`$((s[…]+1))`**: We'll need to back up one day, plus an additional day if following month starts on Sunday (weekday 0) or an additional two days if it starts on Monday (weekday 1).

   The array `s` is incomplete; the arithmetic works because empty string concatenates with `+1` to give the result we want.
4. **`date -d$m-$((…))day +%A\ %eth`**: Format that last working day, appending `th` to give a candidate ordinal.
5. **`|sed s/1th/1st/`**: Rewrite `31th` as `31st`.  The last working day must be in the range 26th...31st, so there are no `nd`s or `rd`s to consider.

---

#### Full demo

```sh
#!/bin/bash

last-working-day()
{
s=(1 2)
m=1$1+month
date -d$m-$((s[`date -d$m +%w`]+1))day +%A\ %eth|sed s/1th/1st/
}

test "$*" || set -- $(for i in {0..35}; do date -d 1jan00+${i}month +%b%Y; done)
    
for i
do
    printf '%s: %s\n' $i "$(last-working-day $i)"
done
```

Output (no args):

```
Jan2000: Monday 31st
Feb2000: Tuesday 29th
Mar2000: Friday 31st
Apr2000: Friday 28th
May2000: Wednesday 31st
Jun2000: Friday 30th
Jul2000: Monday 31st
Aug2000: Thursday 31st
Sep2000: Friday 29th
Oct2000: Tuesday 31st
Nov2000: Thursday 30th
Dec2000: Friday 29th
Jan2001: Wednesday 31st
Feb2001: Wednesday 28th
Mar2001: Friday 30th
Apr2001: Monday 30th
May2001: Thursday 31st
Jun2001: Friday 29th
Jul2001: Tuesday 31st
Aug2001: Friday 31st
Sep2001: Friday 28th
Oct2001: Wednesday 31st
Nov2001: Friday 30th
Dec2001: Monday 31st
Jan2002: Thursday 31st
Feb2002: Thursday 28th
Mar2002: Friday 29th
Apr2002: Tuesday 30th
May2002: Friday 31st
Jun2002: Friday 28th
Jul2002: Wednesday 31st
Aug2002: Friday 30th
Sep2002: Monday 30th
Oct2002: Thursday 31st
Nov2002: Friday 29th
Dec2002: Tuesday 31st
```

Comment: Woohoo! Shell ahead of the golfing languages.  At least for now; I expect that won't last long..

Comment: Save one more character by replacing `s[$(date -d$m +%w)]` with weird `s[\`date -d$m +%w\`]`

Comment: Thanks @gildux - sometimes ingrained good habits are detrimental to one's golf...

Answer (score 6):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), -F 55 bytes

```php
<?=date('l jS',strtotime("$argn+1month last weekday"));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DczRCsIgGIbh813FjwTbKJnaaMSqnXUDnXZizJrlVPQfo5vPPPweeD8/@ZROw3mUqKrSwPtW7iIGdKhnVZGNDC@75bOzOIGREWFV6jPKL6nrPg2XXJK7JT00jVUrGG0VPF0ACUHJUT6MAregX3Kn88O8GNQ@o7bZYhJM7ClnhWC8o0wU/NC1lB3zbrP/nEftbEz0@gc)

Input is in "yyyy-mm" format in my example, but `strtotime` supports many formats

It's so rare that PHP is competitive! I knew one day would be the glory of this pile of unconsistent mess, that I came to like golfing with ;) I needed to add one month because using `strtotime` without a day number returns the first day, and `last` is actually a relative term (opposite of `next`).

Probably still golfable, still searching for edge cases where it could not work (relative month `+1 month` can be broken I think, `-1 month` is for sure)

NOTE: my first version was 4 bytes shorter `++$argn." last weekday"`, I liked it because it uses PHP's string increment, but even if it works with the tests cases, it will fail for December -> "2023-12" would give "2023-13" and `strtotime` is not really clever

Comment: Simply excellent blue elephant. And the better answer by now.

Comment: I was asking myself if Perl could do the same, but it will be a bit more longer because one need to import [`Date::Parse`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date%3a%3aParse) (for `str2time`) or [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) (for `strptime`) :D

Comment: @Kaddath so far this is the shortest answer! You'll be the winner soon if no shorter answers come in :-)

Comment: @gildux yeah we can see here that the creation of PHP came from a need of a set of useful tools for day to day use (rather than from an abstract programming paradigm), the focus was on making some things easier to use. This and the text-parsing oriented nature (great for producing HTML) explain IMO why it remains massively used nowadays, even if "dirty" or "messy". Perl is more for coding experts

Comment: @gildux it's actually the code parsing aspect that made me like golfing with it, in lots of place you can omit spaces and stuff in a weird way, like the space removed in `+1month` because of the way the parser works

Comment: PHP share many aspects with PERL, which was born with also the focus to ease text-parsing in system scripts: that's why people can write dirty and unmaintainable things… But it was also though to allow more traditional programming ways (it tend to embrase many paradigm) However, it's a very old langage so it standard miss some stuffs are missing from it's standard library.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 129 bytes

*-1 thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*
*-2 thanks to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)*

Expects `([year, month])`, as integers.

```javascript
f=(D,d=31,s="st")=>(q=new Date([...D,d])).getDate()>9&&q.getDay()%6?q.toLocaleString("EN",{weekday:"long"})+' '+d+s:f(D,d-1,"th")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1BC4IwAAXge79iDLIN52gqisLqYrfo0jE6DJ1mjS3bKCL67cvqWMf3Ph7vKK7C1pf@7CJtGul9y1FFGp4wYjm0DmK@QAPX8gYq4STaUUpH32NMO@k@FV4UQTB84x3habYcqDNrUwslt@7S6w7B1QaSx03KUyPuJVRGd/CJwxmYhU1oy/Z9GTEC3QFiXxttjZJUmQ61aBfP44Sw@fg4@RGWExD/EZblKQHF302aEMBG8S8)

Or **[126 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc1BC4IwAAXge79iDNIN53AaicLs4rFbR@kwdJolW7qRSPTbzeqYx/c@Hu8qHsKUQ3u3vtKVnOeao5xUPGLEcGgsxDxDPVdyBLmwEhWU0sXPGNNG2m@Fs8Rx@l@cEN7uDz21@qhL0cmTHVrVoIA8RylvlZhS2GnVwBf2XOB6lWfS@vPnMwLtBeK51MroTtJON6hGRRiEEWHBcrf5ExYTEK4I28c7ApLVzS4igC0yvwE)** if we assume a default English locale.

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                 // recursive function taking:
  D,                  //   D[] = [year, month]
  d = 31,             //   d = day, starting at 31
  s = "st"            //   s = suffix, initialized to "st"
) =>                  //
( q = new Date([      // build the date q for:
    ...D,             //   the year and month stored in D[]
    d                 //   the day d
  ])                  //
).getDate() > 9       // if the resulting day is greater than 9
&&                    // (i.e. we didn't overflow to the next month)
q.getDay()            // and the 0-based day-of-week index
% 6 ?                 // is neither 0 or 6 (Sunday / Saturday):
  q.toLocaleString(   //   return the name of the day
    "EN", {           //   obtained with toLocaleString()
      weekday: "long" //   set up to English
    }                 //
  ) +                 //
  ' ' +               //   followed by a space
  d +                 //   followed by the day
  s                   //   followed by the suffix
:                     // else:
  f(D, d - 1, "th")   //   recursive call with d - 1 and s = "th"
```

Comment: [131](https://tio.run/##ZY3LDoIwFET3foVpIvSGRygQDCTFje6MG7@goaU@oBXaaIjx2xF0ZVzOmcmZC7szU/Xnmw2U5mKs6djSUlI8@JwmxDcUGYuAlrijSjyWW2bF1LUB8TlAKIX9EChzx@m@ccCwyjZdaPVeV6wRR9uflcRod0D@8yHElbOhQI1WEr3Ac5euxz1TyPlxsiJ7QjBWWhndiLDREteYRIDjKE4AFr9FPHOy/uM5YJKt0z9O5n06ecY3)

Comment: [129](https://tio.run/##JY1PC4IwHIa/igzSDefwDwQJs0vdoktH6TDcz2WtLd1IJPrsZgXP5X3ew3MVT@GaoXv4xFgJc8sX8J1KXmTUceQ8IrzCPTcwBjvhAdeMseU/E8IU@J8i1SYM@/@cMFmttz3z9mAboeHkh84ojPZHRF8jwE2KqUTaGoXeJI6CKJaxK9tvMsko8hdE5sYaZzUwbRVucZ2neUGzdCnOHw), taking input as `[y,m]`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.text.english`, 110 bytes

```
[ last-day-of-month dup weekend? [ friday< ] when
dup day-name swap day>> dup ordinal-suffix [I ${} ${}${}I] ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TU87TsNAEO1zilfQ2opNRPhEhg65oUFUlovBO4utrHfN7loOQpyExg05AZfJbdjEkoM0o5n33ny_95Iqb-x42L8850-Pt6hIsRZk5yRm_aYaV6MlX8eed35mqKrYOWMdtmw1KzTas-2MIs-oTPvaaArDXRyaLDncLRbpMr1EskSCjQhVWSCSNdIzTq7WK9z811ehYcY_vZfR9UEXUOR8JOgjMjJqjfY1RN9hYN6Gs-9RQNomyBuUGGrWJ_VYrqlluIFOKMtOvLEinKoi10vZ7FDkuPj8OnqwvEQ5bf0toFUYFz7rjGO89yQeJmkcp_gH)

Takes a timestamp (date object) as input.

- `last-day-of-month` get the last day of the month
- `dup weekend?` is it a weekend?
- `[ friday< ] when` then change it to the Friday before
- `dup day-name` get the day name ("Monday", "Tuesday", etc.)
- `swap day>>` get the day number of the month
- `dup ordinal-suffix` get its ordinal suffix
- `[I ${} ${}${}I]` interpolate it all together and print

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 129 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
def f(y,m,d=31,s="st"):
 try:q=date(y,m,d);1/(q.weekday()<5);print(f'{q:%A %d}{s}')
 except:f(y,m,d-1,"th")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY_BCoJAGITvPsUiiLuxlquWtWbQo0i7ixLqqn-UiIeeo4uXeqfepkQ7dPuYGYaZx0u3kJbFMDwvoJzt-67qMkciAQlZLlGW67KGhSGkQgq3NKci9hltYrMBk3ADQd3yKh7zk0sitsLV8irlWSQtJvs1iXSdFYCV3VXcOiJL9F3T28RA8naSGvjc6zBqQmqSechBYc_1fMpcYozIQuqNxDZhQHeTFnzticbgH04tv1sf)

Comment: I love how the `try` does double duty, very clever.  Also your recognition that only 31 needs the "st" suffix.

Comment: The "st" default parameter is from Arnauld, I can't take credit for that.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>99 89</s> 102 bytes

```ruby
->y,m{(1..4).find{|d|(A=Date.new y,m,-d).wday<5}
A.strftime"%A %d#{A.day>30?'st':'th'}"}
require'time'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcrRCoIwFIDh@z3FUOQ42IZHDSLSEHoRa5MGKjUnIuqzL72s2///7PiYfVN4Uc68W2KUMmeyMb1aVrXGVXGvnZa9nui@uVBMTqqer6eNVHJwtnGm00FU0UiFSyX3VWbJDQYHF3Av2IKNWP0ZjdVwSPBva3pHG/ms2zamaYI5R2Q8IAENaVFSOJJAFOkZyD9OM44J@4GpyBCI/wI)

**Explanation**

Anonymous function tacking year and month as numbers.

We find which of the last 4 days of month ( checking backwards using -d ) are  wdays (week days 0-indexed) less than 5 saving each time date object in constant A for later use.

When it's found loop is stopped so A is the last weekday of the month.

Then we format the output, we can only have 31st or XXth.

Comment: ITYM 31st or xxth.

Comment: @Neil yeah! Where is my mind??

Answer (score 4):

## POSIX shell, 168 bytes

Not the shortest possible with the shell, but it doesn't use any bashism and is funny (see explanation bellow.)

```sh
cal $@|tail -2|awk 'NF>1{split("S Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri",d)
a=6;if(NF==1){b=$1-2}else if(NF==7){b=$6}else{a=NF;b=$NF}
print d[a]"day",(b==31)?b"st":b"th"}'|tail -1
```

With the following limitations:

- months are given as integer only, not strings (January or jan for example)
- separator is changed from slash to blanks (i.e. `1 2043` instead of `1/2043`) which is natural shell arguments separator

#### Explanation

We can use the POSIX [`cal`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/cal.1posix.html) to visually catch the last weekday.

```
$ # for February 2017
$ cal 2 2017
   February 2017      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
          1  2  3  4  
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11  
12 13 14 15 16 17 18  
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  
26 27 28
```

The last week is on the visually shown last line (but there's an extra blank line), so with POSIX [`tail`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/tail.1posix.html) (for golfing purpose, `tail -n -2` is shorten `tail -2`)

```
$ # last week of February 2017
$  cal 2 2017 | tail -n -2
26 27 28
```

Finally we should pick the last day… Because the column position vary, [`awk`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/awk.1posix.html) is a better candidate than [`cut`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/cut.1posix.html) here (But one can prefer `perl` or some other scripting langage, but I'm trying to use commands that should be always available), hence the following script:

```
BEGIN  { # on start, create array of days names 
         split("Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa", d)
       }
NF > 1 { # on filled line, print last column name and value
         print d[NF],$NF
      }
```

If the script is put in file `LastDay.awk`, our chaining become:

```
$ # last day of February 2017
$  cal 2 2017 | tail -n -2 | awk -f LastDay.awk
Tu 28
```

However, note that the first column is Sunday, and we need to deal with boundaries. The modification is:

```
BEGIN  { # on start, create array of days names 
         split("S Mo Tu We Th", d)
       }
NF > 1 { # check last column
         if (NF==7) {
           print "Fr",$6 # Saturday: we read the previous field
         } else if (NF==1) {
           print "Fr",($1-2) # Sunday: we count two days less
         } else {
           print d[NF],$NF # Week-Day: pick column name and value
         }
      }
```

For golfing purpose,

- I try to use ternary operator (which is an expression that expects three other expressions) without success
- Initial array creation is not done in `BEGIN` but each time, and rule is evaluate in any case…
- Replace `$1 $2` with `$@` (thanks Toby Speight for the comment) and remove extra spaces

But, in order to comply with the output requirements, we have to add more characters for days.

```
NF > 1 { split("S Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri", d)
         if (NF==7) { # sat
           print d[6] "day",$6
         } else if (NF==1) { # sun
           print d[6] "day",($1-2)
         } else { # non w-e
           print d[NF] "day",$NF
         }
      }
```

For compliance, we have to deal with ordinals too. To avoid repeating ourself many times, let's opt for assignments and put formatting at end.

```
NF > 1 { split("S Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri", d)
         if (NF==7) { # sat
           a=d[6]
           b=$6
         } else if (NF==1) { # sun
           a=d[6]
           b=($1-2)
         } else { # non w-e
           a=d[NF]
           b=$NF
         }
         print a "day", (b==31)?b"st":b"th"
      }
```

#### Addendum

Well, `cal 12 2001` shows that there wasn't simply a blank line as I believed, the formatting is for six weeks… Then, before invoking AWK, our selection should be changed so:

```
- cal $1 $2 |                  tail -n -2
+ cal $1 $2 | grep -v '^ *$' | tail -n -1
```

Alternatively, the AWK output (`Friday 28th` and `Monday 31st`) must be filtered though `tail -n -1`. Either add 14 characters before (and save `NF > 1` condition), or add 10 characters after (and keep 4 characters condition). Fifty-fifty, so it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, 153 bytes

```py
from datetime import*
T=timedelta(1)
def f(m,y):
 d=date(y+(m>11),m%12+1,1)-T
 while d.weekday()>4:d-=T
 return d.strftime('%A %d')+['th','st'][d.day>30]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzLCoMwFET3@YpsJElNizdKX6DQf@iudCHcBKVGJb2l@PU2QgvS5Zw5M@NEzdDnxzHMswuD51iTpdZb3vpxCLRh13KJaDuqJSiG1nEnvZ7UmXEsF11OqfQVgNI@AZOCBrW9Mv5u2s5y3L2tfWA9SVUVZ9yWsQmWXqGP1ZOCW96lSC48QaHSm6BGaPEkcb/hLs6qPLvPY2h7kk5Cpk1mcqXYj5gI4LACJw37Q7ECEI1iPQHzfwLwJfMH)

Comment: [133 bytes](https://tio.run/##XcxBCoMwEAXQfU6RjZjUWJxUaiso9A5eQEiCoUZDOkU8farQgnQ57//5fsVhni43H2I0YXZU9ajROk2t83PAE@ma/VR6xJ4BJ0obapgTK68JVc1eZ2vGXAvAhUtAZiCA5x2hy2BHTdV50fqp@pXxtqxV3mxJ0PgO0xa9MJh9naXJgyYKh5RHH@yEzDAohCzkhXPyE7kBVAe4C7hW5QFga5THF5D/IwBfiR8 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @SuperStormer Thank you very much, updated

Comment: Unfortunately, [153 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYzLCoMwFET3@YpsJElNizdKX6DQf@iudCHcBKVGJb2l@PU2QgvS5Zw5M@NEzdDnxzHMswuD51iTpdZb3vpxCLRh13KJaDuqJSiG1nEnvZ7UmXEsF11OqfQVgNI@AZOCBrW9Mv5u2s5y3L2tfWA9SVUVZ9yWsQmWXqGP1ZOCW96lSC48QaHSm6BGaPEkcb/hLs6qPLvPY2h7kk5Cpk1mcqXYj5gI4LACJw37Q7ECEI1iPQHzfwLwJfMH "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") to handle the "st"/"th" properly.

Comment: @SuperStormer Thanks, updated

Comment: -2 bytes: `d.strftime('%A %d')+'tsht'[d.day>30::2]`

Comment: I tried using a little math to eliminate the `while` loop but it ended up being a character longer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>137</s> 136 bytes

```
≔Ｉ⪪Ｓ/θ≔⁻⁺×¹²⊟θ⊟θ²θ≔ＥＥ²⁻θι﹪Σ⟦÷ι⁴⁸⁰⁰±÷ι¹²⁰⁰÷ι⁴⁸÷ι¹²÷×¹³⁺⁴﹪ι¹²¦⁵⟧⁷θ≔⊟θη≔⊟θθ≔⁻⁺²⁸﹪⁻θη⁷∨¬θ⊗¬⊖θθ§⪪”⟲1Ｕ↘α‹¬@²¦À≧≡FGv_Ｅ✂₂↘” ⁺θηday Ｉθ§⪪stth²‹θ³¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHJasMwEL33K4ROI3CJt9JAT6GmYGhSgw09lBxcW9gCW14khfbr3fESQ9z2oGXmPb2Z0cvKtM@atBqGg1KikPCcKg1xWwkNoWyNjnUvZAHMInRHGR4de7pbuEchjYKowi0RNVfguBaJmha6kbhe3M2rtJ0WcmeBziJi5B2b3FQNxKaGj1DqQFxEzkFYxN/bNuInXqSaww3kuAghtuFvM457k1m69bDJsXl/rT1TR8EHdsb9cTPxPJNFyt@pv//F3a/a67DlVfith1Ojp9dBYz4rnk9xwLOe11xqjPED2bWHCJ3QcNChzPnX4hElKC9JYrgi7zyXeCSl6RV56QVFzwhly5BTYbbK0Dz9RvAaTrZ37L8qSuuSzk6@cjWJec6oNgzOzrV9b7i/VD8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses my code for Zeller's congruence from my answer to [ASCII Calendar Planner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/173800/).

```
≔Ｉ⪪Ｓ/θ
```

Split the date on `/`.

```
≔⁻⁺×¹²⊟θ⊟θ²θ
```

Convert to months since March 1, 1 BC.

```
≔ＥＥ²⁻θι﹪Σ⟦÷ι⁴⁸⁰⁰±÷ι¹²⁰⁰÷ι⁴⁸÷ι¹²÷×¹³⁺⁴﹪ι¹²¦⁵⟧⁷θ
```

Use a modified Zeller's congruence to extract the day of the week of the first day of next month and this month as a list.

```
≔⊟θη≔⊟θθ
```

Extract the list entries into variables to save bytes.

```
≔⁻⁺²⁸﹪⁻θη⁷∨¬θ⊗¬⊖θθ
```

Calculate the last working day of the month.

```
§⪪”...” ⁺θηday
```

Output the day of the week.

```
Ｉθ
```

Output the day of the month.

```
§⪪stth²‹θ³¹
```

Output the ordinal suffix.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 104 bytes

```
S½⌊Ḃ÷dN„4/?›13*5/⁰14=[¹›₁1"4*₁JḊ÷¬∧∨28:›"i|30⁰⇧5%₂+]:£Wf⌊∑7%:¥∇2<[›-6]⇩`°⋏ ß₀ †ƛ ßɖ »£`⌈ið„:31=«⟇'Ḋ«½iW∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJTwr3ijIrhuILDt2RO4oCeNC8/4oC6MTMqNS/igbAxND1bwrnigLrigoExXCI0KuKCgUrhuIrDt8Ks4oin4oioMjg64oC6XCJpfDMw4oGw4oenNSXigoIrXTrCo1dm4oyK4oiRNyU6wqXiiIcyPFvigLotNl3ih6lgwrDii48gw5/igoAg4oCgxpsgw5/JliDCu8KjYOKMiGnDsOKAnjozMT3Cq+KfhyfhuIrCq8K9aVfiiJEiLCIiLCIyMDIzXG4xMSJd) | [All test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBIiwiIiwiU8K94oyK4biCw7dkTuKAnjQvP+KAujEzKjUv4oGwMTQ9W8K54oC64oKBMVwiNCrigoFK4biKw7fCrOKIp+KIqDI4OuKAulwiaXwzMOKBsOKHpzUl4oKCK106wqNXZuKMiuKIkTclOsKl4oiHMjxb4oC6LTZd4oepYMKw4ouPIMOf4oKAIOKAoMabIMOfyZYgwrvCo2DijIhpw7DigJ46MzE9wqvin4cn4biKwqvCvWlX4oiRIiwiIiwiMjAyMywgMTBcbjIwMTYsIDE0XG4xNjc0LCA5XG4yMDQyLCAxMyJd)

Takes the year and the month (one-based) seperately. January and February are considered the 13th and 14th months of the previous year.
Vyxal has no Date/Time built-ins, so this uses a variation of [Zeller's Congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence).

```
S½⌊Ḃ÷dN„4/?›13*5/⁰14=[¹›₁1"4*₁JḊ÷¬∧∨28:›"i|30⁰⇧5%₂+]:£Wf⌊∑7%:¥∇2<[›-6]⇩`°⋏ ß₀ †ƛ ßɖ »£`⌈ið„:31=«⟇'Ḋ«½iW∑


S½⌊Ḃ÷dN„4/?›13*5/ ­⁡​‎‎  ## First Part of Zeller's Congruence Formula⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
S½⌊                 # ‎⁡Split year into two halves [century, year of the century]
   Ḃ                # ‎⁢Bifurcate, push this and its reverse
    ÷dN             # ‎⁣Push each item to stack, multiply the year of the century by -2
       „            # ‎⁤Rotate stack ([century, year of the century] is on top)
        4/          # ‎⁢⁡Divide both by 4
          ?›13*5/   # ‎⁢⁢Multiply month + 1 with 13/5


⁰14=[¹›₁1"4*₁JḊ÷¬∧∨28:›"i|30⁰⇧5%₂+]­⁡​‎‎  ## Calculate number of days in month⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
⁰14=[                             ]  # ‎⁡‎⁡If month is 14 (February) ...
    [                    |             # ‎⁢‎⁢Leap year calculation:
     ¹›       Ḋ                        # ‎⁣Does year + 1 divide ...
       ₁1"4*₁J                         # ‎⁤... [400, 4, 100] (Pair [100, 1] * 4 and join 100)
               ÷¬∧∨                    # ‎⁢⁡‎⁢⁡Split on stack, logical not, and, or
                ¬∧∨                    # ‎⁢⁢[ (year + 1 divides 4 and not 100) or (year + 1 divides 400) ]
                   28:›"i              # ‎⁢⁣Index into [28, 29]
                         |        ]  # ‎⁢⁤‎⁢⁤Calculate days for other months:
                            ⁰⇧5%₂      # ‎⁣⁡((Year+2) % 5) % 2 == 0
                            ⁰⇧5%₂      # ‎⁣⁢Maps [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1] for months 3 to 13 (March=3, ..., January=13)
                          30     +     # ‎⁣⁣Add result to 30

:£Wf⌊∑7%­⁡​‎‎  ## Second Part of Zeller's Congruence Formula⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
:£        # ‎⁡Save a copy of number of days in month in register
  Wf⌊∑    # ‎⁢Wrap terms in list, take floor and sum all terms
      7%  # ‎⁣Result modulo 7 (Returns weekday as Saturday=0, Sunday=1, ...)

:¥∇2<[›-6]⇩`°⋏ ß₀ †ƛ ßɖ »£`⌈i­⁡​‎‎  ## Calculate workday (as day of the week and month)⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
:¥∇                            # ‎⁡Push the number of days in the month (register), weekday, weekday
   2<[   ]                     # ‎⁢If weekday < 2 (Saturday or Sunday)
      ›-6                      # ‎⁣Subtract weekday+1 from number of days in month (last workday), Push 6 (Friday)
           `°⋏ ß₀ †ƛ ßɖ »£`    # ‎⁤Compressed string of workdays
          ⇩                ⌈i  # ‎⁢⁡Index workday-2 into list (Monday=0, Tuesday=1, ...)

ð„:31=«⟇'Ḋ«½i­⁡​‎‎  ## Day of the Month formatting⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ð„             # ‎⁡Push space and rotate stack
  :31=         # ‎⁢Is the day of the month 31? (Returns 1 or 0)
      «⟇'Ḋ«½i  # ‎⁣Compressed string "thst", halve and index into string

W∑  # ‎⁤Join all values in the stack (workday as day of the week, space, workday as day of the month)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 118 bytes

```powershell
param($y,$m)for(;!((($k=Date "$y/$m/1"|% *hs 1|% *ys(--$d))|% d*k)%6)){}"{0:dddd} {0:dd}"-f$k+('st','th')[$k.Day-ne31]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1db4IwGIWv6a9413SjdWXyYXQfMSHRebtlemfMwqAERcTRmo0gv50Vp85kvaGc5@k52/xLFDIR67UV5oVoSDysmm1QBBklJScZi/OCPl1RSkk6HAdKACZll2RdB@@voZNIcNpvKallkYgx/RN1UnbdZ6yqcWU/RvrUcLjU2IpJektNqUxuqsRkc5LejYPS2gjPWTQ1Qj5FBvepT13b9Tg4NuOAZzsho6AEz5EKs7PgDDi4l9y9V8mZO/1Bj8NDyyfF8h927V7bf4E9@4AZ7GGSF89BmFgvHysRKqiQQZSQahRIwYGI761ORQRDIO8alSIodJzlG5W02UnVqBByt1Y6vCExHMSjh4z563S0kyrPfkcWvl4xprswFFK2Lcenlvj8W9QGnul2CHU9vtwCa5UvN4C7WDtvp9VjCTJqVKPmBw)

Takes in two parameters, `$y`ear and `$m`onth, returns a `string`.

Less golfed:

```powershell
param($y,$m)
for(;(($k=(Date "$y/$m/1").AddMonths(1).AddDays(--$d)).DayOfWeek-in"Saturday","Sunday")){}
"{0:dddd} {0:dd}"-f$k+('st','th')[$k.Day-ne31]
```

Finds the last day of the month, while it is a Saturday or a Sunday, check one day before
Then formats the date

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>270</strike> 250 bytes

```c
char*s[]={"Mon","Tues","Wednes","Thurs","Fri","sth"};l(y){return y/4-y/100+y/400;}
f(m,y){int d,p=l(y);y-=d=m<3;d=6+y+p+(31*(m+=12*d-2))/12;
d+=y=31-(12652612>>(m*2-2)&3)+(m>11&p-l(y));d%=7;y-=p=d&d/4*3;
printf("%sday %d%.2s\n",s[d-p],y,s[5]+(y<31));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/NasMwEITveQpjcJAsqdZK/iEoyrG33gI9JD4EK64NlWvk5CCCn92VWxroZXc@ZphlG/bRNMvSdBeXTqdaP@K3ryGm8fF@ncJ6v5rhRxy7u1v3q@vDnG5dPKtP5PHDXW93N0Q@y5nPgHMSFOdq3rTI0uD3wy0ydNRrWHmmjbZ7qYwuiScjQRJSZIkGkRomMM5AKEO01xIYAlEWogRxOCCbimBvJSbIHgC2I1v7sDKJrtbWUZutyfJUqs3owskWxclkLj5KTPIipnN4aToZNtbUB1HUBPm9hFAwL/bSDwg/NlEUtaiisCskVr8EnAounigCQfVHOwpllT@jwcv/JTkPNC/f)

Doing it the hard way - a bunch of mod 7 math to count extra days since the first Monday of Year 0.

`p=l(y)` returns the number of leap years since 0.
`d=m<3` is true for Feb and March
`y-=d...m+=12*d-2` sets `m` to the month, where Mar is 1 and Jan and Feb are 11 and 12 of the prior year.
`d=6+y+p+31*m/12`  sets d to the number of extra days between the first Monday in year 0 and the last day of the prior month.   (the 31*m/12 gives the correct pattern of +3s and +2s)
`(m>11&p-l(y)` is 1 if it's February of a leap year
`12652612`  is "31-days" for each month encoded in 2 bits, so
`y=31-(12652612>>(m*2-2)&3)+...` sets y to the last day in the query month.
`d+=y...;d%=7` gets the day of the week (0==Mon) for the query.
`p=d&d/4*3` sets p to the days needed to truncates Sat/Sun to Fri (4)
`y-=p` fixes the last day of the month
`s[d-p]` is the day string,
2 characters from `s[5]+(y<31)` is "st" or "th"

Comment: [224 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY4xa8MwFIT3/Aqj4iBZUq0nOTZBUcZu3QId0gzBz24MsSvsZBAm/euu09JAp7uPO44r5UdZTtMTVnXTVdE5CmkmQwpK8dkptUiG/cGN5PWzI4LsrtUwy1uF3Y/Zna79XV/6htwsWm9r2orARu/ONkiHrt0Yiy7ngXtuIKEtd6ATlJqloC1yF5wBSUHnK52D3m518iXbpWGctluApZdnZjF2xX3OO1ximiXG@r7pLjUl8YDHEMUYP@vhfX447FH6gwiCDJcT4TRsDDBmb1N7bDrKxkUURTUtBKxXhtlfAiW00g/UM0HxR2sBeZE9qnOW/WsqNdNt@gY "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets / Microsoft Excel, 76 bytes

`=let(d,workday(eomonth(A1,)+1,-1),text(d,"dddd d")&if(day(d)=31,"st","th"))`

Put the month and year in cell `A1` in one of the formats specified in the question (or any other valid date format), and the formula in `B1`.

The formula gets the first day of the *next* month and then finds the previous weekday before that, which is the same as the last weekday of the specified month.

The day number of the last weekday of a month will never end in `2` or `3`, so it is enough to add `st` when the day is `31` and use `th` with any other date.

The formula is for Google Sheets, but I tested it in the most recent version of Microsoft Excel for the web and it seems to work the fine there as well.

The Google Sheets [epoch](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) is 30 December 1899. The formula will work with dates from January 1900 to December 99999. In Microsoft Excel, the range of valid dates seems more limited, and formula will work from January 1900 to November 9999.

| input | expected | formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/2023 | Tuesday 31st | Tuesday 31st |
| February 2017 | Tuesday 28th | Tuesday 28th |
| 09/1674 | Friday 28th | #NUM! |
| 1/2043 | Friday 30th | Friday 30th |

Answer (score 3):

## (Pure) [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 126 bytes

```sh
zmodload zsh/datetime
s=strftime
for d ({31..9})$s -sT %A\ %dth `$s -r %F $1-$d`&&[[ $T = [^S]*$d\th ]]&&break
<<<${T/1th/1st}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcqxCoMwFEDRPV/xhhi0EM1TqQg6dOkP1E0ttcSQ0oqQZFL89tQK3Q6Xu1jtVRiFfplm@ZkHCYvViRzc6F7TSGxtnVEH1WxAQrhmGMflFlEL3DYQXDoIpNPw@AUDwRUociofjLUt0AZqaO@3/kRlt099z9jTjMObVFVF1yZBpxO0bvMRIQpSkWZcZH@hOIQFF@kuPBc5F@XR8v1D/wU)

Using the builtin `strftime` rather than any external programs.

```sh
zmodload zsh/datetime
# "strftime" is long enough that setting $s and using $s twice is shorter than "strftime" twice.
s=strftime   

# start at the 31st of the month, count downward
for d ({31..9})
    # Get the timestamp of "YYYY-MM-DD" with strftime -r (reverse/strptime)
    # and find "Nameofday DDth" from timestamp. (-s)ave in $T
    $s -sT %A\ %dth `$s -r %F $1-$d` &&
    # if Nameofday begins with an S or we end up on a different day of month
    # (like 02-31 converted to 03-03), keep going.
    [[ $T = [^S]*$d\th ]] && break

# Fix suffix
<<<${T/1th/1st}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 66 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⊃'Dddd DDoo'(1200⌶)⊃⌽w/⍨0≠6|7|w←∊{0::⍬⋄,¯1 1 ⎕DT⊂⍵}¨(⊂⌽⍵),¨25+⍳6}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37U1azukpKSouDikp@vrmFoZGDwqGebJlD4Uc/ecv1HvSsMHnUuMKsxryl/1DbhUUdXtYGV1aPeNY@6W3QOrTdUMFR41DfVJeRRV9Oj3q21h1ZogFg9e4EcTZ1DK4xMtR/1bjarBQA&f=S1MwNFAwMjAy5kpTMAIyDM2BDEsFQzNzEyDDEChiYgwA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

woo-hoo. Shaggy waiting room. Takes date as `m y`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 234 bytes

```go
import(."fmt";."time")
func f(m,y int)string{M,e:=Month(m),"th"
t,W:=Date(y,M,31,0,0,0,0,UTC),(Time).Weekday
for w:=W(t);t.Month()!=M||w<1||w>5;{t=t.Add(Hour*-24);w=W(t)}
if t.Day()>30{e="st"}
return Sprintf("%s %d%s",W(t),t.Day(),e)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVHbbtNAEBWP3a-YrmRpF02NL4GWhI1UkSJeUlXUKA-AkBWvUyv4UnusYLn-El6iSrzxQ_AJfAW7dQBVK-1lZs7ROWe_3W_K_Y8qXm_jjYY8zorvLaUnZz9_Z3lV1iRcnubEZy6nLNdcsrQt1pCKHDvICpIN1Vmx6Zeop2pZFnQjcomcbjgjXE3VIiYtOlxi6KN3WO-j1xJFZOiku9J6m8QdS8sadlO1EiRn5I5E8lgt7-52r3yzzZ_PelLknieJeFu29dOTYCJnuwfAwLIUyF3EnZDz0Ou14g3xgdWa2rqA68oopFRwpwEncRqOFoQHAGo5jI5_PampqzREYDy1a4KeHeVlgZ2Oa2uVHemvFYx-2TDmYPMS0kySbqiBqYIPn6Ke9b6HgReEyKNWN8YfhL6VhKwPTMM__d8IzkxWtvES_RenE-Rv6uxR3TeASfivHnpjfWDsyvr6UgiulILr6PxdBOZmv8iE-RnJyqnjwnzrqK5n8fqhmApyrTNyrTdp4yu3U5OuMaiUGZrBcbmFHq7-JucFyTPHmySg5uDcgnBuJTj0seAIIxWMXAgGbR-GCQ2phMEofSQULi4XcBDKDtHv9-P5Bw)

#### Explanation

```go
import(."fmt";."time")
func f(m,y int)string{M,e:=Month(m),"th"
// start the date off at the 31st of the month, regardless of the month
t,W:=Date(y,M,31,0,0,0,0,UTC),(Time).Weekday
// subtract 1 day while...
for w:=W(t);
// the months don't match, or
t.Month()!=M
// the day is not a weekday
||w<1||w>5;{t=t.Add(Hour*-24);w=W(t)}
// replace "31th" with "31st"
if t.Day()>30{e="st"}
return Sprintf("%s %d%s",W(t),t.Day(),e)}
```

Answer (score 2):

## bash and BSD date, 96 bytes

As an alternative to [Toby Speight's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266286) but using BSD implementation instead of GNU one

```sh
s=(1 2)
m="-v$2y -v$1 -v+1m -v1d"
date $m -v-$((s[`date $m +%w`]+1))d +%A\ %eth|sed s/1th/1st/
```

It has the following limitations:

- months can be integers only, not strings (`October` or `sep` for example)
- separator is changed from `/` to blanks which is natural shell arguments separator

There's certainly room for tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 152 bytes

Since there is already multiple python answers I've tried to use the calendar library since I never used it before.
It just uses the fact that the object monthcalendar gives weeks of the month and days of those weeks as a 2d array ->then just a check for highest number in the first 5 days of last week.

```python
from calendar import *
def f(y,m,d=31,s="st"):
 if d in monthcalendar(y, m)[-1][:5]:
  print(day_name[weekday(y,m,d)],str(d)+s)
 else: f(y,m,d-1,s="th")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TU9LCoMwFNx7ioerpI3QKEIVvECvIFJCk1SpSSRJKd6k0I2b9k69Tf1Cl_Nm3nxen673tdHD8L57GR2_T2mNggtrhebMQqM6Yz3sAi4kSNQTRXiRUOKK0PkQ5wE0Ejg0GpTRvt7-RiEoXEa0KvO0GlXQ2UZ7xFl_1kyJ8iHEbQSLIa6I8xZxvHc4ANE6kW9Z0Rzl6xCv_U7SWBipKbKcNBjmy4Qt01eBaJalJD7E8cKoP4bQBE9tZvPVcVv-Aw)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms thank you, looking forward to my stay and hopefully mastering some actual skillz

Answer (score 1):

## [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 143 bytes

```cs
(y,m)=>new[]{DateTime.DaysInMonth(y,m)is{}z?z:z,z-1,z-2}.Select(x=>new DateTime(y,m,x).ToString("dddd dd")+(x>30?"st":"th")).First(x=>x[0]!=83)
```

Explanation

```cs
f = (y, m) =>                       // lambda that takes year and month
  new[] {                           // create new implicitly typed array
      DateTime.DaysInMonth(y, m)    // get number of days in month
          is {} z ? z : z,          // hack to set variable z to this value inline
      z-1, z-2                      // add the 2 days previous to z
  }                                 // array contains the last 3 days of the given month in descending order
  .Select(                          // transform the elements of the array
      x => new DateTime(y, m, x)    // create new datetime with the given year and month
      .ToString("dddd dd")          // convert to string and format
      + (x > 30 ? "st" : "th"))     // add "st" if is the 31st, "th" otherwise
  .First(                           // get first element that matches condition
      x => x[0] != 83)              // first character is not "S" (i.e not day isn't saturday or sunday)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVNtT9swEP7eX3FYk7BFyPqCBmtpEVA6sTFtWqvtA/DBJG7rLcRd7EDSkN/enV3aBtRNmqU4Z99zzz13lwR6P9ByMUjj4FjGxgO3aZPIeNKDMXRhQXPvnnV7sXi8vi363IiRvBd@n@f6Mv6sYjN1AKmLcn4yb8@9@X4Dn2bpD0UkAkMzFwurSIv2MuaP1NBloSTEBWFI2B7Neq36CdGGtImZEsb8gUy0o8iu67c73aMWW3RqNSeXrvSyjeAJCs6gi8pp5l8acd/wYGk0GcY98ASM0AZRTpIMjFQxT/JtZJTVihrgKoA2682WB406eskoFTrkObQaqBNKb4NpHHrQrEKaR1hFBdJ4d3jgwXsLGSRyG6JZP7CJKohW3SFqJer/kho68VwJtpzag5IhKKv9@hY0s4UPc43V@n3JJ7HSRgba74u7dOL/SKQRVzIWdFmf/1HJmO56u1gwQzbHNaPq7icO7T/IrBBtODrBUaDG41MPznrUTcmZMPaqzV7ehR7cKRWBiqN8OFWPAy4jjZMZ80iLVe/txGZcaxGip95xd2OVCB5MgVrnr4cZjg1Ctuyg21eBIpthFCL87zxKRWftPIOJMpvjsiEuz@bSJPna3tDahbFWJrXEn0TOOi@8z2r3uhbnX/xOsRyKShicQAPaqyKqcNiGJV9Ph0OCAWRwenlFNlHl2gq4sW24yAIxs70Fwf4pORRjnkaGnrGtGoT/QZhRPhO08neyauK1KcdAd14O7ukJdl5V8Tc15yrWKhKVr@gNGdPiuZ8lg30orKYSKDK24YYU@C5viGdH6s74xjMj7HVflvu2DLafF/0lswjLt0Xon6s0NuWKZBX0TfDQxeB9ufgD)